# How to show SSO login ONLY using AWS Amplify React Authenticator? (remove email/pwd sign-in option)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I want to remove everything but the "Sign in with Google" button in this Authenticator component (screenshot).  I am able to hide the "Create an account" tab with the `hideSignup` flag, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the "----or----" and email/pwd signup (as well as the "Forgot your password?") that comes after.

Current code:

```
// src/pages/login.js
import React from 'react';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

const SignInPage = () => {
    return (
        <Authenticator 
        hideSignUp
        >
        {({ signOut, user }) => {
            return (
            <main>
                <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
                <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white"
                onClick={signOut}
                >Sign out</button>
            </main>
            );
        }}
        </Authenticator>
    );
  };
  
  export default SignInPage;
```

package.json versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^6.0.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.0.4",
    //...
  }
```

[image: authenticator screenshot]